# Modelling Biprobit using the ML command on STATA

Tags: maximum-likelihood, stata

For a research project, I am trying to replicate some built-in MLE commands using the ml stata routine.

Specifically, I am trying to replicate the results from the biprobit command.
I successfully replicated simpler likelihood functions (e.g. probit, linear ...) but I think I am doing some mistakes with the biprobit.

I am using the following code:

```
program mybiprobit_lf
        args lnfj xbo xbt p
        
        qui replace `lnfj' = ln(binormal(`xbo', `xbt', `p'))                                                     if $ML_y1 ==1 & $ML_y2 ==1
        qui replace `lnfj' = ln(normal(`xbo') - binormal(`xbo', `xbt', `p'))                             if $ML_y1 ==1 & $ML_y2 ==0
        qui replace `lnfj' = ln(normal(`xbt') - binormal(`xbo', `xbt', `p'))                              if $ML_y1 ==0 & $ML_y2 ==1
        qui replace `lnfj' = ln(1 - normal(`xbo') - normal(`xbt') + binormal(`xbo', `xbt', `p'))         if $ML_y1 ==0 & $ML_y2 ==0
        
end
```

The latter is not converging: I keep getting iteration errors. My guess is that I am not translating the likelihood function in the proper way into Stata (I tried with different syntaxes, but without success).

Could you please help me out with this?